# constraintlayout.widget.Group animation not working with TransitionManager

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout

does anyone has any idea why animating `constraintlayout.widget.Group` visibility with TransitionManager is not working? Isn't this widget made for these kind of things?

**It is working if hiding or showing items after separating views from Group**

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
            android:id="@+id/cardHeadersGroup"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:constraint_referenced_ids="cardSystemHeader,cardSimpleHeader,cardCombinedHeader"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/cardCombinedHeader"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/cardSystemHeader"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/cardSimpleHeader"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible"/>
```

```
 val headersGroup = binding.cardHeadersGroup

        val slideIn = Slide()
        slideIn.slideEdge = Gravity.BOTTOM
        slideIn.mode = Slide.MODE_IN
        slideIn.addTarget(headersGroup)

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.root as ViewGroup, slideIn)

        headersGroup.visibility = VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 8):

I've been recently working with `TransitionManager` and `ConstraintLayout.Group` and found it to be very buggy.

Eventually I decided to dump the whole `ConstraintLayout.Group` and created an in-code `AnimationGroup` (similar to the `in-xml` `ConstraintLayout.Group`):

```
class AnimationGroup(vararg val views: View) {
    var visibility: Int = View.INVISIBLE
        set(value) {
            views.forEach { it.visibility = value }
            field = value
        }
}
```

and an extension function for the `Transition`:

```
private fun Transition.addTarget(animationGroup: AnimationGroup) {
    animationGroup.views.forEach { viewInGroup -> this.addTarget(viewInGroup) }
}
```

---

That way you can do the following (almost exactly the same code, but simpler xml - no `ConstraintLayout.Group`):

```
val headersGroup = AnimationGroup(
    binding.cardSystemHeader, 
    binding.cardSimpleHeader, 
    binding.cardCombinedHeader
)

val slideIn = Slide()
slideIn.slideEdge = Gravity.BOTTOM
slideIn.mode = Slide.MODE_IN
slideIn.addTarget(headersGroup)

TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(binding.root as ViewGroup, slideIn)

headersGroup.visibility = VISIBLE
```

Answer (score 4):

We can also extract the Group's referenced views with simple extension function:

```
fun Group.getReferencedViews() = referencedIds.map { rootView.findViewById<View>(it) }
```